# Isomorphism of finite Order on complex vector space diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why is every Isomorphism $\alpha: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ of complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^n $ of finite order (therefore there exist natural number $n$ with $\alpha ^n = id$) diagonalisable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a triangolable endomorphism $f:k^n\to k^n$ is diagonalisable if and only if its minimal polynomial $\mu_f$ is square-free. If $k=\overline k$, all endomorphisms are triangolable. If $f^n=id$, then $\mu_f\mid x^n-1$, which is a square-free polynomial in $\Bbb C[x]$. So, $\mu_f$ is square-free.